# Как написать клавиатуру для отправки запроса на Телеграмм с помощью requests

Tags: python, telegram, клавиатура

Хочу передать вместе с текстом и картинкой Inline кнопку с ссылкой, благодаря aiohttp ClientSession, результат должен быть отправлен в канал Телеграмм.

Что я получаю сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который отправляю:

```
    text = f"""`{title}
\nБыло продано {when_buy}, за {price}`"""
msg = {'chat_id': '@example_channel', 'caption': text, 'photo': img_link, 'parse_mode': 'MarkdownV2'}
async with ClientSession() as session:
    await session.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot1111:AAAA/sendPhoto', data=msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

keyboard = {
        "inline_keyboard": [[
            {
                "text": 'some text',
                "url": "some url"
            }
        ]]
    }

data = {
    "chat_id": some_chat_id,
    "text": 'some text',
    "reply_markup": json.dumps(keyboard)
}
```

Далее отправляете эту `data` в запросе. В вашем случае замените `text` на нужные поля

Comment: Ваш ответ меня вполне устраивает, но это трудно запомнить, можно ли как-то без json? Пример: `buttons = [['some text', url = 'https://example.com']]
msg = {
    'chat_id': '@csgo_sales',
    'caption': text,
    'photo': img_link,
    'parse_mode': 'MarkdownV2',
    'reply_markup': buttons
    }`

Comment: без `json` телеграм ошибку выдаст. можете воспользоваться любым фреймворком для ботов, там создание кнопки будет более понятным